# Modifying growing strategy using custom allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, allocation, allocator

I am not a user of custom allocator, but I was wondering whether a custom allocator can be used to redefine the growing strategy. For example, in most implementations, a `std::vector` grows geometrically. Would it be possible to change this strategy for an arithmetic growth, like adding 10 elements everytime a reallocation is necessary. And if the answer if yes, then how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The reallocation strategy is defined by `vector`, not by the allocator it uses. The allocator is there only to provide the memory - it is up to the `vector` itself to tell it how much memory to provide.

The standard mandates that `push_back` is amortized constant time. From [vector.modifiers]

> Complexity: The complexity is linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end
>   of the vector.

Since `push_back` must be `O(1)`, the growth strategy of `vector` must not be arithmetic - otherwise we'd have linear-time insertion.

To do what you want, you'd have to provide your own `vector`-like container and implement your own `push_back()` member function.